# Composer not generating doctrine-migrations PHP file into vendor/bin directory

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I have inherited an old legacy system based off Yii 1.1 which has had multiple development teams working on it for the past 10 years so is a bit of a mess with little to no documentation.

Doctrine Migrations have been used in the past and I can get this working on Docker, however on the live EB/EC2 instance, the migrations files will not run from command line.

Command:

`php vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations status`

Throws error

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/app/current/site/vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/site/vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations on line 8 

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/app/current/site/vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in /var/app/current/site/vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations on line 8
```

Looking at my local environment versus the live server, no doctrine-migrations.php file has been created in vendor/bin on the dev server, which composer should have created and is the file being looked for. Composer install is run during build on every deployment but I can't figure out why it is not auto-generating this file in the vendor/bin directory - just another file called doctrine-migrations which pretty much just requires doctrine-migrations.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Doctrine\Migrations;

require __DIR__ . '/doctrine-migrations.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

`conposer install` install bundle declared in your `composer.lock` file.
Your `composer.lock` file is generated when doing your first `composer install` or a `composer update` or `composer require`

Difference may occur between your `local` environment and `production` environment.
Indeed, on local, `composer install` install some bundle only needed in `dev` mode (see your `require-dev` part in `composer.json`)

Either the `composer.lock` file is not up to date with your `composer.json` file (if `composer.json` contain the required bundle) either the required bundle is set as `require-dev`

To install it, you can run `composer install doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`

Comment: doctrine/migrations is in composer.lock and migrations file appears in the vendor directory on live.

Wondering if there was a problem with creation of proxy file in vendor/bin though not really sure where to start with that